# Are the Dolphins used to navigate Enterprise D sentient beings or Starfleet property?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Starfleet employs dolphins in their starship navigation systems, which sounds very much like property. This seems contradictory if they are considered sentient

**Contradiction**
In *The Perfect Mate* Geordi takes the Ferengi merchant Par Lenor to see the dolphins in their catacean ops center. This is where the bottleneose dolphins (*tursiops truncatus*) work as "navigation specialists."

> LAFORGE: Listen, have you had a chance to see the dolphins yet? This is something you really just don't want to miss!

The way Geordi talks about them doesn't seem respectful. Would he also say, "Have you had a chance to see the vulcans yet?" It seems more appropriate to say "have you met the dolphins yet" if they were respected sentient beings.

Yet in this same episode Riker is openly upset at the idea that the Krios were transporting a sentient being, Kamala, as property to be exchanged in peace talks between Valt and Krios:

> KAMALA: It is not complicated at all, Briam, and the Captain has no tolerance for prevarication. I'm a gift, to Alrik of Valt.
>   RIKER: You mean you're using this ship to transport a sentient being as property?
>   BRIAM: Not as property, as a gift, and I was concerned that you might not entirely understand.
>   PICARD: Your concern was justified, Ambassador.
>   KAMALA: You're angry. Why?
>   PICARD: There is a provision in the Federation Constitution that protects an individual's fundamental rights.

Are dolphins sentient in Star Trek?

Comment: As far as I know, the dolphins in question were never actually made canonical. (Because where would they get the budget for dolphins?) I doubt there's an answer in the show proper.

Comment: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Dolphin - "*In 2385 Admiral William T. Riker recalled the dolphin crew members of the USS Enterprise in a conversation with Commander Christine Vale, saying that they all liked really bad jokes. (TNG reference: Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual and ST novel: The Poisoned Chalice)*"

Comment: isn't cetacean ops only referenced in the "Battle" Enterprise D in the alternate timeline from Yesterday's Enterprise? If so - then in the 'real' timeline, they just may have a dolphin tank. Nothing canon indicates any of the assumptions in the question

Comment: @NKCampbell - And in the TNG Technical Manual. Which is supposedly canon but also contains a gigantic duck; Sternbach talks about how they never made it into the ship but that he wanted to show them; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual#In-jokes_and_other_items_of_note

Comment: @NKCampbell - Regardless of the timeline dolphins are either fundamentally sentient or they are not, I believe. While "Battle Enterprise" considered them as crew and carries on conversations, that does suggest sentience. The notion that real-timeline dolphins are different bears a burden of proof.

Comment: I think that while "have you had a chance to see" might sound disrespectful in 2019, ala [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/130409), it would not have been considered out of place in 1992.  It is very thin evidence at best for the proposition that the dolphins were considered property rather than crew.

Comment: "The way Geordi talks about them doesn't seem respectful." - IMHO this is a rather weak assumption. "Have you had a chacne to see the Vulcans yet?" might sound inappropriate if you're thinking about seeing Vulcans for their being Vulcan, but it's totally appropriate if, for example, seeing them perform their work (without *meeting* them, i.e. interacting) is in any way worth watching on its own.

Comment: is this actually in the on screen episode - I cannot remember - or just something in the screenplay that was never used?

Comment: @onepound - Both references are in the show. They just love marine mammals, which is why “Journey Home” had whales saving Earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We meet some Cetacean Ops officers in [LD: First First Contact](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/First_First_Contact_(episode)); Lieutenants (junior grade) [Matt](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Matt) and [Kimolu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kimolu).

They seem pretty sentient to me.

They're also weirdly attracted to Rutherford, but that's a whole 'nother story.

Comment: Dolphins being attracted to people was a whole minor sub-plot in David Brin's Startide Rising