# What is the status of cetaceans and other animals of high intelligence on Earth in the 2200s?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Given that Spock was able to communicate with whales, is it known by the time of TOS that whales are of human or near (or superhuman) intelligence?

Do humans routinely communicate with Cetaceans? Are they full citizens of Earth, on par with humans? Have any native Terran, non-human species achieved full personhood by the time of Star Trek?

Comment: Dolphins appear to be people; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220765/are-the-dolphins-used-to-navigate-enterprise-d-sentient-beings-or-starfleet-prop

Comment: Isn't Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home largely about the whale's place on Earth and, didn't it involve more the main writers, directors and producers then most of the franchise?

Correct me if I missed a chunk, and don't we see Kirk (born 2233, so bang on time) & Co having no way to communicate with or obtain consent from the our-time whales but nevertheless taking some back to the future?